# Odd entries for Win32_LogonSession and respective StartTime

Tags: windows-10, powershell, malware, wmi

I'm sorry if this isn't the best place to ask this, but if not here, I'm not sure where else.

I've recently been debugging my computer and trying to see if there is any hidden malware. I've mostly used my PC for gaming, and as Discord is pretty much just a malware farm at this point, I've run into some pretty sketchy people in various gaming communities who I've found out are apparently budding black-hat hackers for the hell of it. In addition, I've had various problems occurring, like BSOD's and kernel fault crashes or whatever after the encounter(s), and strange things like regedit showing up in recent apps before I'd even heard of a registry, and various other oddities, like timezone changes, weird mouse interrupts (maybe?), and anti malware services just not even running correctly (MalwareBytes Chameleon consistently stopped working).

On my first two attempts to identify anything, I ended up bricking the whole damn computer and having to run a fresh install entirely. It sucks, but I've learned my lesson from that, and will try to make better backups of my data before messing with things that I don't understand. I guess I only lost a few worthwhile python scripts anyways, with most everything else being on Google or Steam.

Anyways, I suppose one day I'll have to go through and completely change all passwords, but who knows when that'll even be a safe thing to do.

For now, I just have some questions about the results of a powershell command I've used to find all logon sessions. I've got a bit of coding experience in my past, mostly from python, but it's by no means expert level, and I mostly rely too heavily on code I find elsewhere. Not sure how I found this one, but it's:

`gwmi -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_LogonSession'`

A typical entry looks like:

```
AuthenticationPackage : <string?
LogonId               : <int>
LogonType             : <int>
Name                  : 
StartTime             : YYYYMMDDHHSS.xxxxxx - xxx
Status                :
```

With blank columns being as is on all entries.

My question is concerning two of the columns, AuthenticationPackage (AP), and StartTime.

First off, there are far more entries than you would think there would be, mostly with CloudAP, and Negotiate, and one NTLM. Not sure what any of these are, honestly. I've tried reading up on some of them, but I've had trouble fully understanding the differences between the types. As far as I understand it, these AP's won't tell me that much, but I'll still ask in case they can add some clarification.

The main problem for me is that many of these logons are from well before I booted up my PC, and cross referencing the LogonID with the query `gwmi -Query 'SELECT * FROM Win32_LoggedOnUser'` shows that most of them are signed in using my name.

Learning about how Windows 10 works is an important goal if you're going to use it anyways, and the question "how would one discover the undiscovered malware?" is a fascinating one to me. I just don't want to waste too much time on it, honestly. Windows can be frustratingly opaque for users, and maybe I'm dumb, but the documentation is often either outdated, or hard to understand (usually the norm for documentation anyways...). Not to mention, much of their data collection and software update / download methods on the backend seem to boldly assume that it would be impossible for a hacker to hijack them, when in reality, it just makes it far more difficult for users to have control of their system over a hacker.

Anyways, back to my point: How could a logon session be started before I've even booted up the computer? I think the most simple answer would be that the LogonSession table just includes all the most recent logons, but the LoggedOnUser confirms to me that that's not the case as far as I can tell. All these sessions correspond to a LoggedOnUser entry, these entries all have my username, and thus every single one of them has the same full administrator rights that I would think only one logon would have.

Is this a sign for concern?

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Here is the documentation. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logonsession

Comment: Thank you, but I've already seen the documentation. It doesn't really address my question as to why there would be so many logon sessions for my user, or why they would have a StartTime from before I even booted up my computer.

Comment: Do you really shutdown your computer? No hibernation, sleep, energy saving etc.? Hibernation is enabled by default btw. Is "Use sign-in info to auto finish setting up device after update or restart" enabled? There are many reasons why the start time of your sessions might begin prior to *your login*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not likely to be a cause for concern, but it's worth learning some more about how windows defines a session/logon. First I'll just share what I have on my PC for comparison.

```
Get-CimInstance win32_loggedonuser

Antecedent                                                     Dependent                                  
----------                                                     ---------                                  
Win32_Account (Name = "SYSTEM", Domain = "MyLaptop")          Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "999")
Win32_Account (Name = "LOCAL SERVICE", Domain = "MyLaptop")   Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "997")
Win32_Account (Name = "NETWORK SERVICE", Domain = "MyLaptop") Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "996")
Win32_Account (Name = "NetAdmin", Domain = "MyDomain")        Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "314462054")
Win32_Account (Name = "MyUser", Domain = "MyDomain")          Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "2087657")
Win32_Account (Name = "MyAdminUser", Domain = "MyDomain")     Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "113104563")
Win32_Account (Name = "ANONYMOUS LOGON", Domain = "MyLaptop") Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "231724")
Win32_Account (Name = "DWM-1", Domain = "MyLaptop")           Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "108347")
Win32_Account (Name = "DWM-1", Domain = "MyLaptop")           Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "108305")
Win32_Account (Name = "UMFD-0", Domain = "MyLaptop")          Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "64622")
Win32_Account (Name = "UMFD-1", Domain = "MyLaptop")          Win32_LogonSession (LogonId = "64621")
```

So running through those above, I have these users showing up:

- `MyUser`: My actual logged on user
- `MyAdminUser`: A second account, used for running things as admin. Each UAC prompt basically creates another session. (I cut out the other 15)
- `NetAdmin`: a service account that has logged in remotely
- `DWM-#`: Used by windows to run the explorer UI basically
- `UMFD-#`: Used by windows to load user-mode fonts and drivers
- `*SERVICE`: Service principals used by windows to run the kernel/network/etc
- `ANONYMOUS LOGON`: a windows entity used mostly for impersonation (run as-another-user) or things like changing your own password.

**These are all normal** in a windows domain, plus running things as a different user/admin can add a pile pretty quickly. You may see some software like antivirus or database services etc set up and run themselves as a separate user too.

These all show up as NTLM/Negotiate/Kerberos. You mentioned some of the `Win32_LogonSessions` you're seeing have `AuthenticationPackage : CloudAP`. I don't have any examples on my PC, but those are going to be sessions using microsoft's [CASB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/what-is-cloud-app-security). Generally used by things like MS Office online or other cloud-based apps.

I don't have any sessions older than my last restart time. I think @stackprotector is probably correct that you have fast startup enabled, which saves your windows session when you shutdown. I believe this is as simple as just selecting Restart from the start menu, then checking again for sessions. (I recommend doing this anyways).

But if you're really seeing persistent sessions, you can check out the windows Credential Manager for anything that might have saved logon credentials where "Persistence" isn't set to "Logon Session". Again, I wouldn't really worry about stuff in there either.

---

And finally, I'll say that checking for sessions is not actually useful to see if you've been 'owned'. Real malware can and will hide its presence from the OS, and you won't find it without some real know-how. These days if you're not confident with the security of one of your devices, back up your files, wipe it, download new installers and go - it's easier than ever.

Comment: Fast startup would make sense too, given that I have an SSD, and probably set that up at some point to take full advantage of its quick startups. Thank you for this information.